# OpenTok and ARCore

Tags: java, video-streaming, arcore, opentok, tokbox

I just try to make an AR broadcasting App on Android.
Using ARCore session. I wonder how can I work with at the same time OpenTok Session and ARCore Session?
Because They cant work together. Both of them try to use camera. I just want to render AR on a GlSurface and send with this like Agora IO video consumer to Client side.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The right approach is to to let ARCore to manage the camera and then fetch the image data from the ARCore render and feed it to the OpenTok Session.
There is a sample code using ARCore in the [Opentok Samples for Android SDK](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/pull/251)

Hope it helps to understand how it can work together.

Although it is not Android, the approach is the same when using ARKit. There is another sample in [here](https://github.com/opentok/ARKitSample) and in [this blogpost](https://tokbox.com/blog/build-live-video-app-arkit/)